# How to upload 3 attachments to current post?

Tags: wp-query, functions, uploads, media

I have a form which updates a post but when updating I need to be able to also upload 3 posts:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload1" id="custom-upload2" />
    <input class="form-control" type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload2" id="custom-upload2" />
    <input class="form-control" type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload3" id="custom-upload3" />
</div>
```

The post I am updtaing is a draft which I then make it publish and within the same form I need to be able to also change the title, so within the same template I also have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="theTitle" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="inputTitle" value="<?php echo $myTitle; ?>" autocomplete="nope">
</div>
<?php if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) {
    toPubblish($post->ID); ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="ok" name="pubblish">
    <?php
        if ( get_post_status ($post->ID) == 'publish' ) {
        } else { ?>
            <input id="upTitle" type="submit" name="newTitle" value="BUONA SERATA" class="btn secondary-btn primary-bg">
    <?php }
} ?>
```

And then I do

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
    if ('BUONA SERATA' === ($_POST['newTitle'])) {

        $post = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_title' => $_POST['inputTitle']
        );
        wp_update_post($post, true); 

        if ($_FILES['postImage']) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
               //Add your error action
                } else {
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post->ID );
                }
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
          update_post_meta($post,'bgc_event_pimg',$attach_id);
        }

        ob_start(); //this should be first line of your page
        $myurl = get_site_url();
        header('Location: '.$myurl."/profile/");
        ob_end_flush(); //this should be last line of your page
    }
}
```

And in function I have:

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
}
```

But the images are uploading but are not attaching to current posts and I cannot see them if I see the posts

Comment: Your `insert_attachment()` function is probably not receiving a valid post ID - if it's not valid, the images would be uploaded, but not going to be attached to the target post.

Comment: @SallyCJ and how would I attach it? I am trying so many different way. basically i create a post, save it as draft, then when I open the post, I can change the title and upload 3 images with three forms. I am rally trying so many different ways. Anyhow you could help out with the code?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment; I didn't notice the `media_handle_upload( $file, $post->ID )` in the code. But that `$post->ID` there should be `$post['ID']` because before the `wp_update_post()` call, `$post` is defined as an array and not an object. And the `$post` in the `update_post_meta($post,'bgc_event_pimg',$attach_id)` should also be `$post['ID']`.

Comment: what about this `update_post_meta($post,'bgc_event_pimg',$attach_id);` I don't have that custom field, and I am not even updating it. I simply would need to upload those file to the post as attatchemnts and retrive them later, no need to place them in a custom field

Comment: Check your code in the question. I copied that `update_post_meta()` code from the question. And if you don't need it, just remove it?

Comment: @SallyCJ the whole code is wrong on the question :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86971/discussion-between-rob-m-and-sally-cj).